# How to prevent accidental deletion in Oracle Toad

Tags: toad

Is there a way to configure in Oracle Toad to prevent accidentally execute SQL delete (like ignore delete and update function)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's not.

However, why does that bother you? If you delete something you didn't want to, `ROLLBACK` and everything should be OK.

Also, what is "accidentally"? How can you "accidentally" do

```
delete from some_table where ...;
```

It is quite a lot of typing, can't be *by accident*.

If it is about the toolbar "delete" button, well - that can be by accident. I'm not sure you can restrict that.

Though, you could forbid deleting rows by creating a database trigger, such as

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bd_emp
  2    before delete on emp
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    raise_application_error(-20000, 'Not allowed');
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> delete from emp where ename = 'KING';
delete from emp where ename = 'KING'
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Not allowed
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_BD_EMP", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_BD_EMP'


SQL>
```

Drawback is that you have to create it for every table, separately. It would be great if it worked for the whole schema (but it does not; we can't create such a trigger on the whole schema):

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bd_emp
  2    before delete on scott.schema
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    raise_application_error(-20000, 'Not allowed');
  6  end;
  7  /
  before delete on scott.schema
                         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-30507: normal triggers cannot be based on a schema or a database


SQL>
```

Alternatively, you could create a new user, grant it privileges on current tables (such as `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE`, but not `DELETE`) and let the new user manipulate with data, not the owner (who can do whatever it wants with its own data).

Comment: Thanks, but what if I just type `delete from table_name` and hit enter without specifying the `where` part? It will delete the `table_name` straightaway with 3 words!

Comment: No, it will just move cursor to a new line :) (Shift) F9 will execute it. And you can still rollback. Just don't miss that icon as it is next to commit. Though, there's backup (is it?); also, search for flashback option. Shortly, don't be that scared of deleting something. There are ways out of it.

Answer (score 0):

On the Login window you see your saved connections on the left. There is a column for Read Only. Check that for each connection you wish to protect. This is a nuclear option and will block you from creating and inserting, too. It may be more aggressive than what you're looking for.